# ¿Cómo actualizar un dato automáticamente en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que consume datos desde un API que desarrolle en Nodejs, para traer un dato necesito ingresar un código en un `EditText` y presionar un botón de  `BUSCAR`, al hacerlo me muestra los datos que corresponden a dicho código sin ningún problema. Me gustaría actualizar los datos automáticamente, sin necesidad de presionar este botón, que se pueda detectar cuando se ha ingresado un nuevo código para realizar la petición de los datos.

Intente usar un ciclo que me hiciera peticiones cada cinco segundos, pero la aplicación presentaba problemas de rendimiento y se detenía.

Este es el código que tengo actualmente.

```
public class Inventario extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText campo_texto;
    private RequestQueue queue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventario);
        final EditText campo_texto = findViewById(R.id.campo_texto);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView textview7 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        queue =  new Volley().newRequestQueue(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    ObtenerDatosEan();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        //Ejecutar cada cierto tiempo




    }

    private void ObtenerDatosEan() throws JSONException {

        EditText campo_texto = findViewById(R.id.campo_texto);
        String valorEditText = campo_texto.getText().toString();
        final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject("{ \"ean\":\"" + valorEditText + "\"}" );
        String url = "http://192.168.1.62:3000/ReadEan";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("recordset");
                    TextView textView7 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                    TextView textView8 = findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                    for(int i=0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String referencia = mJsonObject.getString("referencia");
                        String desrefer = mJsonObject.getString("desrefer");
                       // Toast.makeText(Inventario.this,"Referencia: " + referencia, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                       // Toast.makeText(Inventario.this,"desrefer: " + desrefer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                        textView7.setText(referencia);
                        textView8.setText(desrefer);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Inventario.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        });

        queue.add(request);

    }

    public void Validar_Actualizar(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

te recomendaria usar addTextChangedListener en tu editText

Ejemplo

```
    campo_texto.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
                    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { 
                    //El codigo que queres ejecutar aqui. 
                    }

                    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
                    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
                })
```

Lo que si fijate de validar que ingrese una cantidad mínima de caracteres.

La fuerza de la costumbre. en JAVA

```
.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    })
```

Comment: Al parecer el esta trabajando en java, creo que le facilitaría si le pones el ejemplo en java

Comment: La fuerza de la costumbre.